# The Terminal: 多言語サイトのユーザーのためのチャットルーム

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, チャット, 他言語サイトでの提案

この投稿は、@NicolasChabanovsky さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された "[The Terminal: a chat room for international site users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317209/314875)" の和訳です。

---

[image]

成功するための重要な要素の一つに効果的なコミュニケーションが挙げられます。そしてこの度、チャットルーム「[The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)」を紹介できることを嬉しく思います。ここはスタック・オーバーフロー多言語サイトのユーザーや私たちのコミュニティに情熱を注ぐユーザーのための場所です。チャットルーム開設にあたり少し改善点を述べたいと思います。

1. **多言語サイトユーザー同士でのコミュニケーション。** 私たちは多言語コミュニティが[日々の問題について話し合い](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323)タイムリーに情報交換ができる、そして気軽に知りあえる場所を作る必要があると思います。
2. **必要とするものを理解する。** コミュニティが何を必要としているのかを理解するためのベストな方法は、まずはユーザに耳を傾けることです。多言語サイトのメタで起こっている情報を私は充分に得ていないようです。私はStack Exchangeの社員として多言語サイトのメタの案件をできるだけ多く知りたいので、あなたが必要だと思ったらすぐにチャットルームで教えてください。
3. **タイムリーなサポート。** 私は多言語サイトのユーザーがサポートを必要とする際にStack Exchangeの社員の誰かとチャットで話せていなかったことが残念です。サポートが必要なときはいつでも「The Terminal」のチャットルームで私([@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky))にメンションを飛ばしてください。もちろん日本語でも大丈夫です。お気軽にどうぞ！

どうぞ[チャットに参加してください](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)！多言語サイトのグローバルなユーザーとチャットで話し、そしてあなたのコミュニティにサポートが必要な時はすぐに私に教えてください！

---

> **"The Terminal"におけるルール** ([原文](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47288083#47288083)):
>
> 1. 他のユーザーを尊重し、[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)に従いましょう。
> 2. バグや機能要求の報告にはMSEを利用してください。
> 3. ユーザーに関わる問題の窓口には、モデレーターにコンタクトしてください。
>
> このチャットルームではあなたの得意な言語を使用することができます。
>
> **どんな手助けをしてくれますか？**
>
> 私はコミュニティマネージャーです。その主な目的は、多言語サイトを支援し、それらが成長するのを手助けることです。私はこのプロセスのコミュニティセクションを担当しています（つまり、このサイトの技術的な部分には触れていません！）コミュニティマネージャの注意が必要な場合は、遠慮なくpingしてください。特に:
>
> - コミュニティのためのアイデアやイニシアチブを持っていて、ブレインストーミングしたい場合。
> - コミュニティにおける問題について、新たな視点が必要な場合。
> - コミュニティでの決定に従ってサイトの設定を変更する必要がある場合。
>
> また、私たちは翻訳に関連する話題をこのチャットルームで議論することもできます :)
>
> ようこそ!

---

Comment: [ルール](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47288083#47288083)です＼(^o^)／

Comment: ルールも翻訳して本文に含めてみました。